# Apple's Application Loader not uploading. Freezes and resets

Tags: ios, application-loader

Application Loader refuses to upload my app. It worked fine a few days ago but not on the latest build. It uploads 586 bytes, then does nothing for a few minutes, uploads about a meg, does nothing for some minutes, slowly adds a megabyte chunk every few minutes until after a few megs, starts again from scratch. There are no error messages; just this eternal cycle of restarts.

Also while uploading, internet access on other devices slows to a complete crawl.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a dodgy router. This was extremely misleading as all other internet access was normal (stream TV, view web pages, upload files), as was network traffic (network game testing worked fine).

I post this situation and resolution here in case someone else suffers the same issue. Nothing more frustrating than nearing the end of a project and having some random gremlin get in the way and feel isolated because the internet has no answers and no-one shares your pain! If you are having network related issues deploying apps, consider your router as a possible culprit even if it otherwise seems to work.